# switching on String in Netbeans with Java 7

Tags: java-7

I can't seem to get switch statements to work with Strings even though I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Netbeans and have set JDK 1.7 as my default Java Platform. Am I missing something simple? When I try to compile I receive the error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)"

I don't understand why the compiler thinks I am using source 1.5 when I have set 1.7 as my default. Anyone have an answer? Thanks.

Comment: which version of Netbeans IDE you are using ? Bcz In Netbeans 7 has  java 7 as default so whhen tested the switch on string works fine .. @user1868038